# Clone element when input is filled jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, clone

So, I have an input asking for a number of moviments

```
<label for="nmoviments">&nbsp; Number of Moviments: &nbsp;  </label>
      <input type="text" name="nmoviments" id="nmoviments" value="" size="1" required></td>
```

and I have another div which is a toggle for a form of new moviments

```
<div id="darktheme" class="newmov" onclick="toggle4();"> + New Moviment</div>
```

It opens a table with a form full of input fields.

What I'm trying to do is a function that clones the new moviment div with it's new respective toggle form table, according to the number of moviments the user has entered. For exemple, if the user types 3, it should open 3 new moviments divs.

So far, I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nmoviments").change(function(){
        var max= $("#nmoviments").val();
        for(var i=1; i<= max; i++) {
        $('.newmov').clone().insertAfter('newmov');
        }
    });
});
```

But it won't clone the element, nothing happens. So, any suggestions? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for insertAfter() should be based on classname (missing ".")

Also, if you try to call clone() in every iteration, it would clone the entire div and you will get clones in factorial.

You could make clone of first div with classname "newmov" and append it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nmoviments").change(function(){
    var max= $("#nmoviments").val();
    for(var i=1; i<= max; i++) {
      $('.newmov:first').clone().insertAfter('.newmov:last');
    }
  });
});
```